# Importance of Qul

Tags: sharia, practical-islam, islamic-basis, dua, death

I have read that there is [no importance](http://www.khalidzaheer.com/qa/326) to Qul/Khatam or Barsi, but people do it. When someone does Qul of a deceased one, what should one recite? I don't know how to read the Quran except for a few Qul's, Ayat-ul-kursi etc. so what else can I do? And if someone visits the deceased grave. What dua should one read? Some people read really long Dua's when next to a grave and I feel guilt for making dua and leaving  quickly.

Comment: Except with ayat al-Kursi and Khatm I'm uncertain about the terms used here. Would you mind explaining qul, khatam and barsi?

Comment: @Medi1Saif barsi is a yearly anniversary, Qul is after 3-4 days of death. Khatam is every now and then e.g. 6- days or sometimes u give it to ward of evil e.g. u call people for them to read Quran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you visit deceased grave, you can read any portion of Quran (fatihah, small surah, etc.) with the intention of sending the rewards to the dead person.

There are no precise time or day to do this, you can do it whenever you want... You can also do it from home.

Answer (score 1):

Best Is  Surah Mulk as it gives one protection from the punishment of the grave.

One of the companions of the Holy Prophet Hazrat Muhammad (PBUH) has already repaired his tent on a tomb without knowing it. When he came to know the tomb, he recited this Surat al-Mulk. Then he went to the Holy Prophet Hazrat Muhammad (P.B.U.H) and related the incident and his recitation of Surah Mulk. Prophet Hazrat Muhammad (PBUH) said:

“It is the prevention of the punishment of the grave”.

If you want give him its reward you may recite this beneficial Surah.

Jazakallah Khairan